# Graph request Facebook iOS swift not working Im trying to take the user data and upload it into app Cloud Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, facebook, google-cloud-firestore

```
@IBAction func buttTapped(_ sender: Any) {

func facebookLogin(){
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
       loginManager.logIn(permissions: ["publicProfile", "email"], from: self) { loginResult in
                   switch loginResult {
                   case .failed(let error):
                       print(error)
                   case .cancelled:
                       print("User cancelled login.")
                   case .success(let grantedPermissions, let declinedPermissions, let accessToken):
                    print("Logged in!")
                    self.fetchUserProfile()
                 }
           }

   }


}//
```

this is the fetchuserprofile function below

```
func fetchUserProfile() {
      let graphRequest : GraphRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters:   ["fields":"id, email, name, picture.width(480).height(480)"])

    graphRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
         if ((error) != nil)
        {
             print("Error took place: \(error ?? "" as! Error)")
        }
        else
        {
            let result = result as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let picture = result["picture"] as! Dictionary<String, Any>
            let dataObj = picture["data"] as! Dictionary<String,Any>

            var emailValue = result["email"] as! String?

            if emailValue == nil {
                emailValue = ""
            }
            let name = result["name"] as? String
            let id = result["id"] as? String
            let imageUrl = result["url"] as? String

            // Update data to firestore

        }
    })
}
```

im getting errors like Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type 'LoginManagerLoginResultBlock?' (aka 'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')

and if I try fixing that then it tells me the cases are not found here are images below what im trying to do is take some user info and upload it into Cloud Firestore any help information would be helpful
[image]

Comment: You appear to be having some issues within the `LoginManager` function closure. What is `LoginManager` in this use case? Is it the `FBSDKLoginManager`? What is returned in `loginResult` - that may be a FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult object so you'll need to check the docs on the properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Solution this is working on my side.

```
@IBAction func btnFBClick(_ sender: UIButton)
{
    let fbLoginManager : LoginManager = LoginManager()
    fbLoginManager.logIn(permissions: ["email"], from: self)
    { (result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let fbloginresult : LoginManagerLoginResult = result!
            // if user cancel the login
            if (result?.isCancelled)!
            {
                return
            }
            if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
            {
                self.getFBUserData()
                // fbLoginManager.logOut()
            }
        }
    }
}

func getFBUserData()
{

   if((AccessToken.current) != nil)
   {
      GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start(completionHandler:
                { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                    if (error == nil)
                    {
                        if let data = result as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            let firstName  = data.object(forKey: "first_name") as? String
                            let lastName  = data.object(forKey: "last_name") as? String
                            let name = data.object(forKey: "name") as? String

                           if let email = data.object(forKey: "email") as? String
                           {

                           }
                           else
                           {
                                self.view.makeToast("We are unable to access Facebook account details, please use other sign in methods.")
                           }
                        }
                    }
            })
        }
}
```

Comment: How is this related to the logging into facebook issue the OP is showing in his question?

Comment: yea how does this relate to fixing the error? how would I implement it into my code?

Comment: I have added code for login with FB and then get data using graph API please check.